# How to cite within a reference entry using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In my bibliography I have a reference to a talk and another reference to the cartoons rendering of the concepts covered in the first talk.

My solution is to cite both entries in the text and to put a reference in the addendum field of the cartoons rendering:

```
@ONLINE{Pink2010,
    author = {Daniel Pink},
    title = {Drive: The surprising truth about what motivates us},
    url = {http://comment.rsablogs.org.uk/2010/04/08/rsa-animate-drive/},
    addendum = {Versione cartoon di \cite{Pink2010a}}
}

@ONLINE{Pink2010a,
    author = {Daniel Pink},
    title = {Drive},
    url = {http://www.thersa.org/events/vision/vision-videos/dan-pink-drive}
}
```

Is this the correct way to enter these references?

Comment: @henrique: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, that depends on the standards you're following. But it makes more sense to me if the second version (the "cartoon") pointed to the first through `crossref` field. So you should have

```
@Online{Main-ref,
author = {Author},
Title = {Title},
url = {url}
}
```

and

```
@online{Secondary-ref,
crossref = {Main-ref},
url = {new url},
addendum = {Explanation of the difference between the versions}
}
```