# How to cite another reference entry in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

In BibTeX, I need to cite another entry as a note/comment of a first one, something like:

```
@article{Paper1,
author = {Author A.},
journal = {The Journal of XX},
number = {1},
pages = {4252},
year = {2000},
note = {see updated results in \cite{Paper2}    }
}

@article{Paper2,
author = {Author B.},
journal = {The Journal of YY},
number = {2},
pages = {1},
year = {2001}
}
```

Could you give a suggestion in doing this?

I think my need is not really fitting to what proposed here:
[How to cite within a reference entry using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13663/how-to-cite-within-a-reference-entry-using-biblatex)

Comment: Your example bibliography will work fine the way you typed it.

Comment: you have to run `(pdf)latex bibtex` several times. The citation to paper2 is not visible to `bibtex` in the first run. Thus you have to run `bibtex` again after a second `latex` run.

Comment: There is a very extensive discussion/guide for BibTeX at <http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/node22.html>

Comment: @Guido -- I think the question is valid (if not a duplicate); in which case, your comment could be turned into an answer pretty easily: `latex --> bibtex --> latex --> bibtex --> latex --> latex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference `Paper2` is not visible to `bitbex` until the note in the reference `Paper1` is inserted in the bibliography. Thus one needs to run `bibtex` a second time.  Thus the workflow  is

```
(pdf)latex
bibtex 
(pdf)latex
bibtex
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

If one wants to avoid the second call to `(pdf)latex`, then one could insert `\nocite{Paper2}` somewhere in the document, and then the reference `Paper2` is visible for the first run of `bibtex`.